# gganimate fails to inherit ggplot2 grouping

Tags: r, imagemagick, gganimate

I'm trying to make an animation using the iris dataset and `gganimate`. This is a sample of my code:

```
library(gganimate)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

iris %>%
  ggplot(aes(Sepal.Length, Petal.Length, col = Species)) +
  geom_point() +
  transition_states(Species, transition_length = 2, state_length = 1) +
  ease_aes("cubic-in-out")
```

**Update::**

Running the above(04/26/2019) returns:

> Error in l$setup_layer(d, plot) : attempt to apply non-function

The above error relates to this [issue](https://github.com/thomasp85/gganimate/issues/313).

Relevant package info:

```
other attached packages:
[1] dplyr_0.8.0.1   gganimate_1.0.2 ggplot2_3.1.1
```

I expected that I would get an animation split along the different Species. However, gganimate seems to only return setosa. I've looked at the documentation that suggests to solve it like:

```
iris %>%
  ggplot(aes(Sepal.Length, Petal.Length)) + 
  geom_point(aes(colour = Species, group = 1L)) +
  transition_states(Species, transition_length = 2, state_length = 1)+
  ease_aes("cubic-in-out")
```

This however doesn't seem to make a difference. Perhaps I'm missing something. Your help is greatly appreciated.

**EDIT:** I have also tried this but it returns nothing:

```
library(gganimate)
library(magick)
animate(ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, disp)) +
          transition_states(gear, transition_length = 2, state_length = 1) +
          enter_fade() +
          exit_fade(), 
        renderer = sprite_renderer())
```

Comment: Is this still a problem for you? I just tried the first set of code & everything works fine. If it's some pre-CRAN era issue with the package that can no longer be reproduced in the current package, suggest we close it as such...

Comment: Thanks. I will try again some time later(not very active) and update on whether to close.

Comment: @Z.Lin I'm not sure why it doesn't work. I just run it and it gave me an error as updated.

Comment: Hmm, I'm still on ggplot2 3.1.0 & gganimate 1.0.1. That seems to be at last part of the reason (according to the GH link you found).